# Primefaces push on glassfish 3.1.2 Exception

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish, atmosphere, grizzly

this is my config.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
    <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

is the counter example, when clic after 3 or 7 then:

> WARNING: GRIZZLY0024: Terminate process interrupted.
>   java.lang.InterruptedException    at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1325)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.tryAcquire(Semaphore.java:414)    at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.terminateProcess(ProcessorTask.java:1021)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.finishResponse(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:186)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.finishExecute(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:210)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:133)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.flushPostExecute(CometEngine.java:426)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.interrupt0(CometEngine.java:405)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.interrupt(CometEngine.java:383)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometContext.resumeCometHandler(CometContext.java:442)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.container.GrizzlyCometSupport.resume(GrizzlyCometSupport.java:172)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.container.GrizzlyCometSupport.action(GrizzlyCometSupport.java:184)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.container.GrizzlyCometSupport.action(GrizzlyCometSupport.java:81)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceImpl.resume(AtmosphereResourceImpl.java:317)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.handler.AbstractReflectorAtmosphereHandler.onStateChange(AbstractReflectorAtmosphereHandler.java:146)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.broadcast(DefaultBroadcaster.java:853)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.executeAsyncWrite(DefaultBroadcaster.java:768)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster$3.run(DefaultBroadcaster.java:801)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Comment: could you try with an uptodate version of atmosphere (1.0.13 for example, or 2-beta ?)

Comment: I've tried does not work. Atmosphere and glassfish seems to not get along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried primefaces-push but I just use [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) (primefaces-push is using Atmosphere too). To make it work I have to add those JVM options:

- `-Dv3.grizzly.cometSupport=true`
- `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` (I am not sure if this option is still required with the last versions of Atmosphere)

Maybe it could help you.